# Expand numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to somehow expand numpy matrices, which typically look like:

```
import numpy as np

mtx = np.matrix([[['a','b','c'], ['x'], 3], [['d','e','f'], ['y'], 2],
    [['g','h','i'], ['z'], 1]])
mtx
# matrix([[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x'], 3],
#         [['d', 'e', 'f'], ['y'], 2],
#         [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['z'], 1]], dtype=object)
```

The last column contains number of instances of the resulting matrix, which then should look like this:

```
# matrix([[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x']],
#         [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x']],
#         [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x']],
#         [['d', 'e', 'f'], ['y']],
#         [['d', 'e', 'f'], ['y']],
#         [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['z']]], dtype=object)
```

So, three times 1st row, two times 2nd etc.

I wonder what would be the fastest and/or the most elegant python-way?

Many tnx! PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to repeat the first two columns of each row `mtx[:,:2]` the number of times given by the corresponding row of the third column `arr[:,2]`:

```
>>> arr = np.asarray(mtx)
>>> np.repeat(arr[:,:2], arr[:,2].astype(int), axis=0)
array([[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x']],
       [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x']],
       [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['x']],
       [['d', 'e', 'f'], ['y']],
       [['d', 'e', 'f'], ['y']],
       [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['z']]], dtype=object)
```

The third column needs to be cast to integer values first (e.g. using `astype(int)`). I also found it necessary to treat `mtx` as an `array` for this to work: you can easily turn it back into a `matrix` object again with `np.matrix`.