# Generating logical (binary) long data table from summary (frequency) table with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

In one of my latest [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012266/expand-numpy-matrix) I've got an excellent answer how can I use numpy.repeat functionality to generate so-called long data format. Now, I wonder is there a way to make a logical dataframe (or matrix) that would make some later statistics even easier.

This is what I've produced in "simple" python. But I would so much love to learn how it should be done efficiently using numpy!

```
import operator
from itertools import chain

t=((('a','b','c'),('w','x'), 2),
   (('d','e','f'),('y','z'), 3), 
   (('g','a','d'),('w','z'), 5))

columns=list(set(reduce(operator.add,(x[0]+x[1] for x in t))))

rows=[]

for i, j, n in t:
    row=[1 if e in i+j else 0 for e in columns]
    for i in range(n): rows.append(row)

rows
```

I wonder if that would be the most efficient way? I am just learning numpy and I am truly stunned how great it is! :-)

Thanks! PM

Comment: What are you even doing here? columns order don't matter?(since you use set which does not preserve order)

Comment: In a sense order does not matter until all instances are listed as columns and the last element is used to figure out number of repetitions (rows).